# Pressing the magnifying glass icon on a UiTableView Index

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using the following code to display an index for a TableView.
My problem is that pressing the magnifying glass icon, does not take me to the top of the table, where the search bar is. Every other section of the index works.

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
    return nil;
else {
    //I add the magnifying glass to the index
    NSArray *indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];
    // I return the array for the index after I add the rest of Index items
    return [indexArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:self.sectionsarray];
}


}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
// I set index - 1 so I can compensate for the addition of the magnifying glass
return index -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `-1` section, i don't know and you can use the following code instead for the section at the table header:

```
if(index == 0)     
  [tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mySearchBar.width, self.mySearchBar.height) animated:YES];
return index -1;
```

Comment: As you don't have the section of `-1` index, selecting the title with index 0 (glass icon) does not do what you want. Instead you'll have to handle that case manually and scroll the scroll view content to the top left corner where you have a search bar. That is a content of `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` method.

Comment: Nice solution. I chose to use animated:NO though, as this gave a result like the contacts app. Also as I didn't have an IBOutlet on the search bar, an arbitrary sized rect seemed ok too as long as x=y=0.

Comment: This code works on iOS 6: `if(index==0) return NSNotFound;` :o)

Comment: @Cédric Belin, thanks for the hint, have you ever seen it at documentation or any Apple source-code ?

Comment: Apple's documentation does not specify what value to return if the section is not found. As `NSArray:indexOfObject:` method, I felt that `NSNotFound` return was more appropriate than -1. But I was too quick in my answer (I should have deleted my comment): return NSNotFound has the same effect as returning -1, the view returns to the top of the table and not to the top of the search bar. I was misled because when I did my tests, I was working with a short list (5-6 items). Your answer is definitely the right (until iOS 7?).

Comment: @Cédric Belin, I don't think using `NSNotFound` is a good strategy until that is documented and there's a well-described behavior, that is the same as passing `NSIntegerMax` and I believe you can pass any value beyond `0..numberOfSections` with the same effect. I could imagine that NSNotFound does not provide scrolling at all meaning the indexes are incorrect, but again - that must be mentioned at documentation first.

Comment: @A-Live, you're right:
- if it's not documented, we should not using it. But in this case with NSNotFound, it's easier to understand the developer intention.
- returning NSNotFound (like any other value) doesn't provide scrolling but this is a standard behavior. There's no scrolling at all in Contacs app. Adding scrolling is not the Apple-way as stated Ants.

Off topic: why Apple is returning NSNotFound in `NSArray:indexOfObject:` method? An index is of NSUInteger type and NSNotFound value is NSIntegerMax. Do you see the problem? An array can contain more elements than NSIntegerMax...

Comment: @Cédric Belin, I can hardly imagine the array containing 2^16 objects at 32-bit Cocoa environment :) As for the scrolling, it is not animated but still happens, by scrolling I mean adjusting a scrollView (or the particular tableView) content offset.

Comment: @A-Live, OK :o) By scrolling, I meant animation (replace all occurrences of "scrolling" by "animation" and my comment will be clearer: maybe I should learn English before posting). Returning NSNotFound adjust the scroll view. For NSArray, I also doubt to have more than 2^16 items in real life, but there is clearly a problem of semantics.

Comment: @Cédric Belin, there's no big problem I could see while the constant is documented to be reserved for special use: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html That is also a fairly minimal cut loosing one of billions values for the designes using NSNotFound - until that is unsafe, not reasonable or undocumented. Makes the code pretty clear with a tiny sacrifice.